# Regex removing ? and thereafter

Tags: php, regex

```
$string =  'register?rofl=4whatever&lol=2342'
```

How do I use `str_replace` to remove from everything from the "?" to the end such that my output would be only "register"?

Yesterday I discovered some regex using "preg something" and it works however upon echoing it came with Array => index which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

With simple trick like this:

```
$string = "register?rofl=4whatever&lol=2342";
$new_string_arr_ = explode("?", $string);

echo $new_string_arr_[0];
```

or

```
echo substr($string, 0,strpos($string, "?"));
```

Comment: I think the op doesn't want the ? tacked on the end. The question mark in the question denotes it to be a question :)

Comment: :) Not a problem!